# i have most of the program in parts, just unable to put everything together

Tags: c

This project has to do with the representation and manipulation of floating point numbers in a computer. You are required to develop a computer program, using the ANSI C programming language, that will accept as input the following: 
1. A value representing the base of the numbers that shall be used within the program; for example, if 10 is that value, then the numbers to be used in the program shall be of the form 12.3 and 34.565 
2. Two floating point numbers that are in the base entered above; for example, if the base is 2, then the floating point numbers may be 11.0101 and 1010.011 
3. One operator from among +, -, * and /

Further, you are to create appropriate structures for all of the entities/constructs used in the manipulations in the program. 
In addition, the floating point numbers must be captured in a structure that stores at least two elements, one of which will be an exponent and the other a mantissa. For example, if base 10 is used then 2.5 shall be expressed as having a mantissa of 25 and an exponent of -1. This essentially converts the real number into two integers which are amenable to storage in a computer’s memory.

Comment: What have you got so far?  What is your question?

Comment: What have you done so far? What part of the assignment are you having trouble with? We don't do homework here. We just help out with details and direct problems.

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: You need to be specific about where you are stuck. Can you get the input? Convert it to mantissa/exponent? Compute the result? Display the result? What's the issue?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to interpret your question as "This problem seems overwhelmingly big, although I know lots of pieces I can't get any traction, I just don't know how to start."

And such a paralysing feeling is not uncommon when faced with large tasks, whether programming or not. One major trick is to decompose the problem into smaller bits, and write some of the bits. Once you get started things may become less intimidating.

Here I would start by printing the answer. You might say "but we don't know the answer yet" and I say "just pretend"

```
 int base = 10;

 char * resultMantissa = "34567";
 int resultExponent = -1;
```

Now how would you print the required 3456.7 ?

Then work backwards, if you have some input mantissa and exponent, how would you compute the result. Then how do you get the input? Work step by step.